# Alias in cygwin bash doesn't seem to run in the right order

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to create an alias to use in my Cygwin shell to determine if the Mercurial-managed directory I'm currently in has outstanding changes.  The command "hg st -m" lists all modified files.  Unfortunately it doesn't set an exit value based on whether there are changes or not.  So I have tried capturing the output and seeing if it's not empty, piping it through "wc -l" and checking if that's -gt 0, but I seem to have a larger problem in that lines are clearly not executing in the order I would expect them to.

Here is what I've boiled it down to:

```
alias hgfoo='
pwd
echo L1
localChanges="NOT SET YET"
hasLocal="NOT SET YET"
echo "Before: A${localChanges}Z A${hasLocal}Z"
localChanges=`hg st -m`
echo L2
echo "localChanges: A${localChanges}Z"
echo L3
if [ -n "${localChanges}" ] ; then
    echo L3
    hasLocal="YES"
else
    echo L4
    hasLocal="NO"
fi
echo L5
echo "RESULTS: A${hasLocal}Z"
echo L6
'
```

I put in the "Ln" echo statements for debugging.  When I run it by typing in "hgfoo" in a directory that has changes, I see the following output:

```
/d/hg/succession > hgfoo
/d/hg/succession
L1
Before: ANOT SET YETZ ANOT SET YETZ
L2
localChanges: AL2
localChanges: ANOT SET YETZ
L3
L3
L5
RESULTS: AYESZ
L6
M succession-lib\.actionScriptProperties
M succession-lib\src\main\flex\com\workscape\SuccessionConstants.as
M succession-lib\src\main\flex\com\workscape\succession\nomination\tabmodules\BenchStrengthTab.mxml
M succession-lib\src\main\flex\com\workscape\succession\nomination\tabmodules\BenchStrengthTabMediator.as
M succession-lib\src\main\flex\com\workscape\succession\puremvc\controller\StartupSuccession.asZ
L3
L3
L5
RESULTS: AYESZ
L6
```

When I run it in a directory without changes, I see:

```
/d/hg/employee-profile > hgfoo
/d/hg/employee-profile
L1
Before: ANOT SET YETZ ANOT SET YETZ
L2
localChanges: AL2
localChanges: ANOT SET YETZ
L3
L3
L5
RESULTS: AYESZ
L6Z
L3
L3
L5
RESULTS: AYESZ
L6
```

Even forgetting about the fact that the comparison is not working right, in both cases it seems to be running lines multiple times and in the wrong place.  This is driving me crazy.

Any clues?  Thanks.

Comment: Does that `hg` command run in the background? Does it send its output to stderr?

Comment: Your output shows `localChanges: AL2` not `localChanges: ALZ` which indicates the alias you're actually running is not what you're showing us. Clean up or refresh the aliases in your shell, run it again and then show us what's happening.

Comment: No, the HG command doesn't run in the background, but it would not shock me to learn that cygwin deals with running things in backticks in an unusual way.  I may try writing out to a file or using grep, which will set an exit level.  Hmmm.

Comment: The output not looking right is exactly the problem.  Not only did I launch a fresh shell before running the command, I launched a separate shell before both runs to ensure the first test did not affect the second test.  In both cases all I did was launch the shell, paste in the alias command, go to the directory with or without changes, and run the alias.

Comment: consider using a function() { ... } instead ... i ve never seen such a monster of an alias

Comment: Indeed this doesn't look like it should happen. Is your `hg` a cygwin program? What terminal is this running in (Windows console, some cygwin terminal)?

Comment: hg is a DOS command running in a Cygwin rxvt terminal

Comment: UPDATE: I got it to work.  It was indeed the backticks causing the problems.  I refactored it as "hg st -m | grep -q M", then checked the exit value of grep, which is working perfectly.  I still don't know why the backtick caused that problem.  I will try it in a real bash shell at home tonight.

Comment: @akira: What would be the advantage of implementing it as a function instead of an alias?

Comment: @dj_segfault: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases." .. function can have arguments, functions are not expanded on read, you wont need such a huge quoting block to hold together the subcommands of your alias etc etc etc.

Comment: @dj_segfault if you got it to work it would be appropriate to 'answer' the question, and then accept it once you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug in bash's alias expansion. I could reproduce it on Debian lenny amd64 with bash 3.2.29(1), Debian squeeze i386 with 4.1.5(1), and Windows XP with Cygwin 1.7.7-1 with bash 4.1.9(3).

A few experiments show that the bug is very sensitive to variations in how the alias is used. `hgfoo` or `hgfoo :` exhibits the bug, but `{ hgfoo :; }` and `(hgfoo)` work fine. Using a function instead of an alias also works.

I investigated a bit, trying to extract a smaller example. The weirdness seems to stem from having a newline in the alias. Here is a simple example where bash (3.2.29 or 4.1.9) misbehaves. This alias works as expected (from my reading of Single Unix v3) under pdksh, ksh93, ash and zsh under Debian lenny, namely `oops` prints `foo bar`.

```
$ alias oops='a=$(echo bar)
> echo foo $a'
$ oops
foo foo echo bar
```

The bug may be related to [a reported bug about “strange delayed aliases”](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.bash.bug/browse_frm/thread/46c5218bdaad443e/6ff53e38ba966810?q=alias+newline+group:gnu.bash.bug#6ff53e38ba966810), but that discussion focuses on line continuations (backslash-newline) which is not used here.

---

In any case, use a function! Aliases are for one-liners where you're just specifying some default options for a command. A function would have the additional benefit that you could pass arguments to `hg`:

```
hgfoo () {
  localChanges=$(hg st -m "$@")
  …
}
```

¹ 
<sub>I initially thought this was a Cygwin bug, but as [ak2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2978/ak2) pointed out, this bug occurs under Linux as well.</sub>

Comment: It's not Cygwin specific. I've tried it on a Fedora box and got the same effect. No idea why though, but it must be to do with how bash evaluates aliases.

Comment: @ak2: Indeed this is a long-standing alias expansion bug. (Bug, as in, no other shell behaves this way, I can't reconcile the behavior with POSIX, and I don't even understand what could be going on under the hood.) Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. It was indeed the backticks causing the problems. I refactored it as

```
hg st -m | grep -q M
```

then checked the exit value of grep, which is working perfectly.